# SQL Server - Log File - Zero initialized

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When we create databases, the log file are zero initialized. Can anyone please help me on the below highlight numbers ((**0x5000 to 0x6000**), **(0x6000 to 0x3c6000)**)? These highlighted numbers stand for what…

> 2013-02-23 12:42:36.850       spid51     Zeroing C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2K8ENT\MSSQL\DATA\Instant_Initialization_log.ldf from page 0 to 393216 (0x0 to 0xc0000000)
>
> 2013-02-23 12:43:22.960       spid51     Zeroing completed on C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2K8ENT\MSSQL\DATA\Instant_Initialization_log.ldf
>
> 2013-02-23 12:43:23.410       spid51     Starting up database 'Instant_Initialization'.
>
> 2013-02-23 12:43:23.440       spid51     **FixupLogTail**(progress) zeroing C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2K8ENT\MSSQL\DATA\Instant_Initialization_log.ldf from **0x5000 to 0x6000.**
>
> 2013-02-23 12:43:23.440       spid51     Zeroing C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2K8ENT\MSSQL\DATA\Instant_Initialization_log.ldf from page 3 to 483 **(0x6000 to 0x3c6000)**
>
> 2013-02-23 12:43:23.460       spid51     Zeroing completed on C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2K8ENT\MSSQL\DATA\Instant_Initialization_log.ldf

Once the log file has been zero-initialized why at time of “FixupLogTail” and onwards zero-initialization process is happening again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A page in SQL Server is 8192 bytes long.  The hex numbers seem to refer the byte position of the page.

For example:

```
 "from page 3 to 483 (0x6000 to 0x3c6000)"

 0x6000 = 24576
 24576 / 8192 = 3

 0x3c600 = 3956736
 3956736 / 8192 = 483
```

Comment: Hi Andomore, Thank you so much for your instant reply! Could you also give some light on my below question - "Once the log file has been zero-initialized why at time of “FixupLogTail” and onwards zero-initialization process is happening again?" and In hex number (0x6000) "x" stands for what?

Comment: 0x = Hexadecimal Notation. Or how else would a reader be able to determine if a number is in hexadecimal notation? It supports reading.